# Is it possible to upload photo using foursquare api in Android app?

Tags: android, file-upload, foursquare, android-file, android-photos

I am trying to upload a photo to a venue using the Foursquare API in an Android app. But I get `FileNotFoundExceptio`n at `httpsUrlConnection.getInputStream`. Is it possible to upload photo to venue using foursquare api? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: What SDK or mechanism are you using to do the upload? Please provide more information and preferably where in your code you're seeing errors

Comment: I am using Anrdoid 4.2.2(API 17). I'd like to know if Foursquare blocked api to upload photo.

Comment: You should be able to upload a photo if you make the correct POST request. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/photos/add for full docs on this

Comment: I tried, and I got response code 410. I found out that that code means the resource existed before but not now because it was deleted. Does it mean that Foursquare blocked the api?

Comment: What does the body of the response say? You're probably running into versioning issues: are you passing in a `v` param with your API call? See https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning